# Python - Evaluate every conditions of a conditional statement

Tags: python, conditional-statements

In the following code, if `a()` returns 1, `b()` is not evaluated:

```
if (a() or b()):
    # do stuff
```

How can I make sure all of the functions in the statement will be evaluated no matter their result?
In some languages they use `|` and `||` to differentiate the two possibilities. Is there anything equivalent in Python?
Same question for an `and` statement.

Comment: `if 1 in {a(), b()}:`

Comment: Python also has `|` and `&` which you can use with booleans in the way you want (similar to `or` and `and`) `True & False == False`. They are called "bitwise or" and "bitwise and". If you use them with non-boolean types, they will not give the same result as logical and / or. For example `1 and 2 == 2` vs `1 & 2 == 0`. This is the same as many other languages. It's true that bitwise operators don't short circuit, but that's not the only difference between `|` and `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want the `or` logic without the short circuiting, first evaluate all the operands and then use `any`:

```
if any([a(), b()]):
    ...
```

The list must first be created (meaning the functions will be called and their results returned) before the list is passed to `any` (which returns `True` if any value in the list is truthy).

Please take note, however, that functions should be pure and not induce side effects so as to make hacky workarounds like this necessary.

Comment: I forgot this behaviour was called "short circuit". Therefore, how is it called when it's "not short circuit" ? Simply non-short circuit ?

Comment: @user3548298 it is still short-circuiting, but every operator is forced to be evaluated first. This is not behaviour you would ideally want in your program, because short circuiting is very useful in most situations.

Comment: Can you develop what you mean about pure functions ? In my program I'm working with surfaces from pygame and those two evaluated functions return true if they changed something in their respective surfaces. The code executed in that case is a refresh of an other surface containing the two previously mentioned surfaces. Do you see anything wrong in doing it that way ?

Comment: @user3548298 pure functions return the same result for the same input under any condition and do not change any state externally when called. If your functions were indeed pure, you would not always need to call both of them to evaluate the result of  a() or b().

Comment: To give a little bit more details, those two functions are methods using objects' buffers to update the surfaces. Does it mean it's a bad programming practice to use directly the self.buffer variable instead of putting it in the if statement as input as such : if (a(self.buffer)) ?

Comment: @user3548298 I speak from a general perspective. Unfortunately, I'm not really experienced with pygame enough to decide whether there are no better options than bending the rules of conventional practices. But wherever you can, seek to make your functions pure.

Answer (score 2):

If you need both functions to run, it would probably be cleanest to be explicit and write it out fully:

```
x = a()
y = b()

if x or y:
  pass
```

This makes it clear that the calls should necessarily happen. Hiding that fact in the condition seems like a good way to forget about that requirement in the future, and do a refactor that ends up biting you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use any method that accepts list of functions i.e.

```
if any([a(), b()]):
    ...
```